# Why can the action of a diagonalizable matrix in a vector be written as linear combination of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_d$ and eigenvectors $y_1,...,y_d$. Define $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_d)$ and $P = (y_1,...,y_d)$ unitary.

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, we know that $A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$.

So, suppose we have a vector $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$. Then $Ax = P \Lambda P^{-1} x = \sum^d_{i=1} \lambda_1 c_i y_i$, with $c_i = y_i \cdot x$

My question is: why is $P \Lambda P^{-1} x = \sum^d_{i=1} \lambda_i c_i y_i$, with $c_i = y_i \cdot x$?

It's not so clear to me why this is the case.

Comment: @Azif00  $A$ is diagonalisable. We know that $Ay_i = y_i \lambda_i$, and so when we take all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues together, it becomes $A P = P \Lambda$, which will give the expression above. $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: I guess your matrix is self-adjoint or normal. Otherwise this is false. Also, it should be $c_i = \overline{y_i}\cdot x$ in this case.

Comment: @Azif00 I see. Also, I failed to mention we can take $P$ to be unitary.

Comment: @14tim4 Yeah. I'm sorry. You are right, is $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take the $y_k$ to be orthonormal (equivalently, $P$ is unitary). Then $x = \sum_k (y_k^* x) y_k$.

Hence $Ax = \sum_k (y_k^* x) Ay_k = \sum_k \lambda_k(y_k^* x) y_k$.

Comment: @amsmath: You are correct.

Comment: Apologies! I failed to mention that initially! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @14tim4 If you are content with an answer, it is usual here to check it.